# ListBox Template/Styles in WPF

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a ListBox on a WPF form, with the following look:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Width="200" Height="200" Background="White">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="16" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                                <Image Source="Images/myImage.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

How would I go about adding this to a Template/Style so that all of the ListBoxes can reference one template and all have the same look?

I am confused as how to go about creating a template,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `DataTemplate` a [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) which you can place in an appropriately scoped `Resources` collection:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
       ....
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You can then access the resource in you `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}">
```

Alternatively, you can add the `DataTemplate` as part of a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="MyStyle">
   <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
       <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
             ...
          </DataTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>  
</Style>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
```

You can also implictly target all `ListBox` instances by dropping the `x:Key` in the `Style`.

Every framework-level element has a `Resources` collection, up to the application level, so choose the appropriate collection to target elements at the appropriate scope. Also read about [static and dynamic resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#staticdynamic) and which is the most appropriate markup extension to use for you.